# Debugging Angular Asp.net Core project and an API project simultaneously in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have an Angular 5 app added to an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC project in Visual Studio Professional 2017. 
It's set to debug on port 12345

In also have a ASP.NET Core 2 Web.API project in the same solution that is set to debug on port 67890.

If I set both as startup projects in Visual Studio using Visual Studios multiple startup projects in order to debug both, then in my browser debug window when browsing the ASP.NET MVC Angular app on http://localhost:12345 I get a problem as it has no way of knnowing in Angular that the API is on another port so I get the error message of 500 (Internal Server Error) when it tries to call the API  since it is looking at the same port and not port of my API project in my solution.

This is the  angular service method using rxjs

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs"
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

loadUsers(): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.http.get("/api/user/")
          .map((data: any[]) => {
              this.users = data;
              return true;
          });
```

which calls the wrong port of http://localhost:12345/api/user/ as it is the port of the MVC project the Angular app resides it when I want it to look the other startup project of  http://localhost:67890/api/user/

Is their a way to put the full URL including the port that angular uses in a config file or is their some other solution to my problem ?
I am only aware of Angular supporting sub folder to the domain e.g. `<base href="subfolder">` but the port precedes that.

Comment: Sure, you can put it in a config file and use it in every call if you so like.

Comment: You always can use this.http.get("http://localhost:12345/api/user") and run two instances of Visual Studio (each with a only project)